# Как с помощью flex разделить элементы

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

два контейнера.
нужно разнести по сторонам контейнеры.
и дать им расстояния.

Можно ли это сделать без
paddig-righ ???

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
}



.listReset {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}



.container {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}



.headerFerst { 
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    font-size: 0;
    padding-top:  10px ; 
    padding-bottom: 10px ; 
} 

.parazit {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

.parazit li {
    /*margin-right: 20px;*/
}

.parazit li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
} 

.headerLeft,.headerRight  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    
    font-size: 16px;
}

.headerLeft {
justify-content: flex-start;
   flex-basis:  70%;
}

.headerRight  {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-basis:  30%;
}



.headerLeft li::first-letter {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}


.headerRight  li:nth-of-type(3),.headerRight li:nth-of-type(4)  {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.headerRight li::first-letter {
    text-transform: capitalize; 
}
```

```html
<div class="headerFerst">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="parazit">
                        <ul class="headerLeft listReset">
                            <li><a href="#">бренды </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> о нас</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> работайте с нами</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="headerRight listReset">
                            <li><a href="#">личный кабинет</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-key"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">ru</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">en</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Классы .row / .justify-content-between / .col-4 - это классы [Bootstrap 4.0](https://getbootstrap.com/) 
Привел их содержимое, чтобы вы видели их реализацию на flexbox.

Можете оставить как есть или подключить bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <style type="text/css">
              .row {
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                margin-right: -15px;
                margin-left: -15px;
              }
              .justify-content-between {
                -webkit-box-pack: justify !important;
                -ms-flex-pack: justify !important;
                justify-content: space-between !important;
              }
              .col-4{
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 1px;
                padding-right: 15px;
                padding-left: 15px;
                -webkit-box-flex: 0;
                -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
                flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
                max-width: 33.333333%;
              }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>
          <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-4" style="background-color: #E6E6E6;" >
              one column
            </div>
            <div class="col-4" style="background-color: #E6E6E6;">
              two column
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```